# Can I add an output style into my sass file?

Tags: sass

Instead of applying an output style when compiling my sass, is there a way of adding the output style (eg `:compressed`) into the file itself so that it's always compiled with that style?

Comment: What SASS compiler are you using? The original Ruby gem? Compass? A port to another language such as [PHP](http://leafo.net/scssphp/)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. I would suggest looking into using Compass to compile your sass instead of the default sass command line tool. With Compass, you create a config file (config.rb) that can include a line to specify your output style. Then, you just run the `compass watch` command, which automatically uses the output style that you specified in your config.

http://compass-style.org/